# In Excel Strings that look like numbers in a column need to be interpreted as just a string

Tags: excel

I have a column in my Excel spreadsheet that has text that look like:

413,781,222

That looks like a number to excel.  I want it to be interpreted as one big string.

How do I do that?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Change the format to text?

Comment: Tried that my friend.  It removes the commas.  Need the commas in my string.

Comment: Chnage format to General?

Comment: Nope Brett.  Still removes the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as soon as excel recognizes it as a number it removes the formatting from the cell value and uses formats to add commas and such.

To maintain the commas you either need to enter the values with a `'` in front or have the cell formatted as a text cell before pasting/typing the value in.

You could also use the function `=TEXT(F4,"#,##0")` to store the values as strings with commas and then copy paste over.

Comment: This does have the downside that it can hide data if the input is not exactly in the correct format. For example, `413,781,222.7` would display as `413,781,222` and lose the `.7`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree its not perfect but is since the value in the original cell is not a formatted number you need to add the formatting somehow.  If decimals are a worry some sort of `if` statement would likely be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I often do this:

```
=A1&""
```

...or:

```
=R1C1&""
```

That'll make a number a string.

Comment: This just stores the original value so you lose all the punctuation added by formatting (the commas).

Comment: @gtwebb - Yes, that is true. Sounds like there's really not a perfect way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Stick an apostrophe `'` in front of the value...

Comment: I have a column of 50000 such strings.  Not going to happen.  If the column has a value 781,669, it displays as 781669 and the apostophe does essentially nothing.  I need that comma.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have this text in Cell A1.

Try using this:

```
=Text(A1,"###,###,###")
```

I did this to your data, then copied and pasted values only, and the value is '413,781,222' commas included.  You can copy/paste your data and let Excel change it to a number, but then...change it back to the format you like with , in the values.

Putting an apostraphe before each cell is so manual!  It works great for limited number of items, but I have learned to hate doing this (obviously spent too much time doing this in the past)

This works for 781669 as well as your original example

[image]